# Delaying actions

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im brand new to this Android game development, and i am currently trying to create a platform game. Is there a way to make certain actions (such as changing variable values) have a few second delay without the delaying mechanism halting eveything else? i have already tried

```
new Thread(){
public void run(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //variable value change
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

method which i found, but it seems like this method stops any background music that is running with it. Ive also tried the `Handler` method but it seems to crash the game. I am using `libgdx` framework.

Comment: What happens when you use a Handler? Have some logcats?

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that your game is running in an endless loop. Usually you will endlessly get your `render(float deltaTime)` called by LibGDX.

You could either just do it yourself like this:

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    countDown -= deltaTime;
    if (countDown <= 0) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or you could use the [`Timer`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html) class of LibGDX instead like this:

```
float delay = 1; // seconds

Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your work
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you plan on doing OpenGL game (I encourage you to), you have the [Renderer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) class which has built int methods: `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`, `onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl)`, `onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl)`, the one you're interested in is `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`.

So, the template of your class that extends Renderer should be like this:

```
public class CustomRenderer extends Renderer {
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((float)(1000/60)); // 1000 milliseconds divided by 60 so you get 60fps
            //Your code here
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl) {
        //Your code here
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreater(GL10 gl) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Though good information in your answer. This doesn't really answer the OP question.

Comment: Well it does provide the delay in a repeatedly called method. However, your criticism can be deemed correct since the OP requested particular actions/variables to be performed/changed.

Comment: I don't get how this is helpful in any way. First of all: there is a libgdx tag here, which is a crossplatform framework which is a wrapper around opengl as well. So this cannot be used here. Furthermore your code doesn't make any sense, since you put the thread to sleep for 16.6ms in EVERY FRAME, which is completely nonsense...

Comment: @noone I am new to OpenGL and libgdx. But is it possible that he uses the 1000/60 to have a gameloop, which runs at about 60 fps? Libgdx has a gameloop as a standart but maybe in openGL you have to implement one byyourself?

Comment: @Springrbua No. Just imagine: If you would have 60FPS, it means that every frame would need 1000/60 ms processing time. But with his code you would already SLEEP 1000/60 ms in every frame.

Comment: @noone yea i heard, that you should (almost) never let your game sleep. But i thought if you "limit" FPS at a high value it is more or less ok. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @noone is right in that this has no practical application. The 1000/60 is to *limit* the game to 60FPS it doesn't get you that framerate. I don't know about libgdx but OpenGL calls that function whenever something calls drawing methods including refreshing/repainting or moving/scaling background.